# Gitlab script does not store the value of the command to a variable

Tags: bash, shell, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a simple script that needs to capture the test coverage which is like this

```
script:
- echo "running test coverage"
- RES="$(npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false)"
- TOTAL="$(sed -E 's/^.* All files \| ([^ ]+) \| .*$/\1/' <<< $RES)"
- echo "Current test coverage is :"
- echo $TOTAL
```

if I run the script directly on my terminal as say ./test.sh it works correctly and echos TOTAL with the number, however when running on pipeline $TOTAL returns the output of RES i.e `npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false`

Sample output https://replit.com/@LeoBaby/SuspiciousTintedModularity#main.sh
Example

```
I am expecting to capture the value 36.95 from RES into TOTAL
```

Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Quotes after equal-sign and at the end must be removed.

Comment: `<<< $RES` is Bash specific syntax. Are you running Bash? `Example

$ echo $TOTAL # does not print anything.` Please post the full gitlab ci execution output. It posts what is beeing executed.

Comment: I beleive that gitlab scripts inside gitlab-ci should be able to run bash, please do correct me if I am wrong. Like in the question basically prints Current test coverage and then nothing on the next line.

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/ It basically says that bash is supported, so I assumed I could use it.

Comment: @KamilCuk I tried adding a sample output. Please let me know if that helps https://replit.com/@LeoBaby/SuspiciousTintedModularity#main.sh

Comment: `gitlab scripts inside gitlab-ci should be able to run bash` gitlab runs a docker container, or something depending on gitalb-runner configuration. Depending on the docker, or configuration, different shel is used. `I could use it.` That you can, doesn't mean you do. Are you running Bash? What docker container are you using? What gitlab-runner are you using? Please post the full gitalb-ci.yml `I tried adding a sample outpu` Please post the output from gitalb-ci/cd web console window.

Comment: @KamilCuk docker image is node 16.13.1 runner used is gnu and I cant run it. pipeline looks like `test:
  stage: test
  image: node:16.13.1
  before_script:
    - npm i
    - npx node -v
    - npx npm -v
  script:
    - echo "running test coverage"
    - bash test.sh`